# Android SDK: List Fragment clicks rows on previous list fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have exactly the same problem as this question except I am using List Fragments:

[clicking on the fragment invokes activity behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190855/clicking-on-the-fragment-invokes-activity-behind-it)

I thought using List Fragments would solve the problem but it still invokes the activity behind the current view.

How do you solve this?
Thanks!