# When I show a fragment the objects below still respond to clicks

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android

I have some fragments that are part of a view pager. Those work fine. However, on top of the fragments in the view pager, I want to put fragments on top of them (ie nested or child fragments). So, in OnCreateView of the parent fragment, I go ahead and declare my child fragment but then hide it right away.

```
        optionsFragment = new TrackOptions();
        var trans = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        trans.Add(trackOptionsContainer.Id, optionsFragment, "Track Options");
        trans.Hide(optionsFragment);
        trans.Commit();
```

Then, in the parent fragment, when I want to show this child fragment, I simply call to show it and when I want it to go away, I hide it again.

At first, I noticed that the child was transparent and I could see through it to the parent. If I then set a background, that problem went away.

However, now I noticed that while I am viewing the child and clicking on screen, the parent will still respond to events (click events) for buttons that aren't visible because they are on the parent, which is covered by showing the child.

I suspect this is because I need to explicitly also hide the parent when I am showing the child. Is this correct? If so, here are two follow up questions that I don't understand.
1. I don't want to re-instantiate the parent each time I want to show it. I just want the one instance that was created when the app launched. If I have to explicitly hide it, how do I show it again while using the same instance of the fragment class?
2. I have read so many different options to get an event when a fragment is shown and I have tried most of them (OnHiddenChanged, OnResume, UserVisibleHint) but none of them seem to work well with this child fragment setup. What even do I use when my child fragment is shown?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Isn't this question duplicated?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190855/clicking-on-the-fragment-invokes-activity-behind-it

Comment: It seems to be duplicated but I did try searching before I posted (as I always do) and this did not come up for me. Maybe my search terms were off. At any rate, this along with the answer below, helped.

Comment: Don't worry. I easily found it because I've been through the same problem before, so I knew exactly what to search. I would suggest closing it as duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your fragment as clickable, thus it will not allow clicks to pass through. Don't worry, as the background of the fragment is not a clickable background, you will not see any clicks.

Comment: This solution helped solve my issue. I did it in code instead of in xml. So, for each control (button, etc..) that I was having an issue with, I did controlName.Clickable = true; Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make your fragment xml parent layout android:clickable="true" now any click won't be sent to fragment back stack